# How to do the callback of tk.Variable inside a list

Tags: python, callback, tkinter

I'm using a list of tk Variables in my GUI. How to make the callback use the i-Value of the traced tk.Variable?

```
 def callback(a,b,c):
     print 'i+2'

 ButtonsList=[]
 VarList=[]

 i=0
 while i<30:

     VarList.append(tk.BooleanVar())
     VarList[i].trace('w',callback)

     ButtonsList.append(tk.Checkbutton(root, text="This is a CB",variable=VarList[i]))
     ButtonsList[i].place(x=x,y=i*20)
     i+=1
```

Comment: I don't think this is the cause of your problem, but you have mismatched quote marks at `text="This is a CB'`.

Comment: @Kevin. I updated now the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your callback in a lambda that adds additional arguments to the function call.

```
def callback(a,b,c,idx):
    print 'i+2'

#later on in the program:
VarList[i].trace('w', lambda a,b,c,i=i: callback(a,b,c,i))
```

Note the `i=i` in the lambda. This is necessary for variables whose value changes after you register the callback. Without it, `i` would always be 30, regardless of which Checkbutton you click.

Comment: thanks for solving it! I will read about lambda to familiarize!